# Enable and Disable Representation Icon

Tags: icons, mobile-application, sharing

I am designing an application. It shows a list of folder which can be **enabled or disabled** to share. How can we make the user to understand it is **Enabled/Disabled** in Iconic representation. When the user clicks the **Enable**, the **Disable** Icon will be displayed and vice-versa.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plan to use icons, how about icons of folders with 8x8px overlays in the lower right-hand corner (google "overlay icons").  Enabled would use a green check in a circle, disabled could use the red cancel (not "x").  You could further emphasized the disabled stated by dimming the opacity of the icon and changing the text color to one with less contrast (like a lighter gray).  You'd need to careful with the gray to ensure you had sufficient contrast since your background is gray too.

Comment: I can't get it clearly. Can you show me sample representation.